# How do I improve my quick sort pivot selection in python?

Tags: python, pivot, quicksort

I was originally using only a single random pivot given by

```
pivots = random.randrange(l,r)
```

Here l and r will be integers that define my range

I wanted to improve the run time by greatly increasing the likely hood that my pivot would be a good pivot by selecting the median of three random pivots. Below is the code I used and it caused my run time to increase by 20%-30%.

```
rr = random.randrange
pivots = [ rr(l,r) for i in range(3) ]
pivots.sort()
```

How do I implement the above to be much faster?

Edit: Entire code added below

```
import random

def quicksort(array, l=0, r=-1):
    # array is list to sort, array is going to be passed by reference, this is new to me, try not to suck
    # l is the left bound of the array to be acte on
    # r is the right bound of the array to act on

    if r == -1:
        r = len(array)

    # base case
    if r-l <= 1:
        return

    # pick the median of 3 possible pivots
    #pivots = [ random.randrange(l,r) for i in range(3) ]
    rr = random.randrange
    pivots = [ rr(l,r) for i in range(3) ]
    pivots.sort()

    i = l+1 # Barrier between below and above piviot, first higher element
    array[l], array[pivots[1]] = array[pivots[1]], array[l]

    for j in range(l+1,r):
        if array[j] < array[l]:
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i = i+1

    array[l], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[l]

    quicksort(array, l, i-1)
    quicksort(array, i, r)

    return array
```

Edit 2:
This is the corrected code due. There was an error in the algorithm for picking the 3 pivots

```
import random

def quicksort(array, l=0, r=-1):
    # array is list to sort, array is going to be passed by reference, this is new to me, try not to suck
    # l is the left bound of the array to be acte on
    # r is the right bound of the array to act on

    if r == -1:
        r = len(array)

    # base case
    if r-l <= 1:
        return

    # pick the median of 3 possible pivots
    mid = int((l+r)*0.5)
    pivot = 0
    #pivots = [ l, mid, r-1]
    if array[l] > array[mid]:
        if array[r-1]> array[l]:
            pivot = l
        elif array[mid] > array[r-1]:
            pivot = mid
    else:
        if array[r-1] > array[mid]:
            pivot = mid
        else:
            pivot = r-1

    i = l+1 # Barrier between below and above piviot, first higher element
    array[l], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[l]

    for j in range(l+1,r):
        if array[j] < array[l]:
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i = i+1

    array[l], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[l]

    quicksort(array, l, i-1)
    quicksort(array, i, r)

    return array
```

Comment: It's sound weird. Why your pivot would be better if you take the median of three random pivots ?

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code.

Comment: your pivot selection is really strange ... Shouldn't the pivot be an element of the list to sort (presumably `l`)?

Comment: @NunzioMeli Quicksort has an average case run time of O(nlogn) with a worst case of O(n^2). In order to guarantee that the runtime is very close to O(nlogn) you need the pivot to always be in the middle 50% of your list. Selecting the median pivot of 3 mean  the pivot you select will have the above property with a high probability compared to a single random pivot

Comment: @mgilson Sorry! I've added the rest go the code. The pivot will be an index for an element that is in the list

Comment: @Kevin I have added all the code

Comment: @MattTheSnake The median of three random pivots is still a random pivot !!! I guess, you have to select not the median of three random pivots but you can take the first element of the array, the last and the medium. sort them and choose the median between these three elements then technique is called median-of-three.

Comment: @NunzioMeli I implemented your suggestion and it worked well. I understand that the median of 3 random pilots (selected by index) is still random but it has a much better chance of being in the middle 50% of values than a single one. Technically selecting the median of the first, last and middle elements is still 3 random ones because you don't know the elements value. By using truely random elements I hoped to avoid O(n^2) for any possible input array. The method you described and I went with doesn't work well for a bimodal distribution with zeros in the middle and on the ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose the pivot in this way:

```
alen = len(array)
pivots = [[array[0],0], [array[alen//2],alen//2], [array[alen-1],alen-1]]]
pivots.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0]) #it orders for the first element of the tupla
pivot = pivots[1][1]
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: I upvoted and marked this the answer because the technique worked well for me. I however used if statements to find the median of my possible pivots and saw a 10% speed up compared to the code above. I am attributing this speedup to the lack of lambda calls (which would be huge in this algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Though it can be outperformed by random choice on occasion, it's still worth looking into the [median-of-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm for pivot selection (and rank selection in general), which runs in O(n) time. It's not too far off of what you are currently doing, but there is a stronger assurance behind it that it picks a "good" pivot as opposed to just taking the median of three random numbers.